# Ruby XML::Builder with hyphen in Element name

Tags: xml, ruby, builder

I'm trying to generate some XML using XML::Builder, but my element names need to have hyphens in it.

When I try I get undefined methods, with the element name being truncated at the hyphen

```
xml.instruct!

xml.update-manifest do
  xml.latest-id @latest_version_update.guid
  xml.download-url @latest_version_update.download_url
  xml.release-information-url version_guid_url(@latest_vesrion_update.guid)
end
```

The fixed version is

```
xml.instruct!

xml.tag! 'update-manifest' do
  xml.tag! 'latest-id', @latest_version_update.guid
  xml.tag! 'download-url', @latest_version_update.download_url
  xml.tag! 'release-information-url', version_guid_url(@latest_vesrion_update.guid)
end
```

Comment: It would help if you formatted the `code` well

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
xml.tag! 'latest-id', "latest ID with hiphen."
```

Comment: This didn't work when I needed to add child elements below the hyphen namespace

Answer (score 4):

I have tried to fix dash or hiphen in xml to do this.

```
xml.send("latest-id") "latest ID With hiphen"
```

For more reference to go this link [xml with hiphen](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/4406393#1078521)